# In C++, how do I create a constexpr aggregate initialization for a struct that has an array of structs in it?

Tags: c++, struct, constexpr

I am working in C++ and I want to create an initializer list for a struct of array of structs and I keep getting the same compilation error.

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct SetpointChange
{
    uint8_t hours;
    uint8_t minutes;
} SetpointChangeTime_t;

typedef struct SetpointChangesDaySchedule
{
    SetpointChangeTime_t dayChanges[4];
} SetpointChangesDaySchedule_t;

typedef struct SetpointChangesWeekSchedule
{
    SetpointChangeTime_t weekChanges[2];
} SetpointChangesWeekSchedule_t;
```

Here is my initializer list:

```
static constexpr SetpointChangesWeekSchedule defaultSchedule = {
   {
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0}
   },
   {
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0}
   }
};
```

I am getting this error:

```
error: too many initializers for 'SetpointProgram::SetpointChange_t [2]' {aka 'SetpointProgram::SetpointChange [2]'}
   75 | };
      | ^
```

My initialization syntax seems to be very correct... I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: Since you are only zero initializing everything you can just use `static constexpr SetpointChangesWeekSchedule defaultSchedule{};`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using the rather old 'typedef struct' mechanism for defining types?

Comment: @MikelF we are using a light type of C++ that doesn't use objects in our company

Comment: @NathanOliver you are right but I put all the values to 0 so that I could have a simple example on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is aggregate initialization, not initializer list. You need to double braces in some places:

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef struct SetpointChange
{
    uint8_t hours;
    uint8_t minutes;
} SetpointChangeTime_t;

typedef struct SetpointChangesDaySchedule
{
    SetpointChangeTime_t dayChanges[4];
} SetpointChangesDaySchedule_t;

typedef struct SetpointChangesWeekSchedule
{
    SetpointChangesDaySchedule_t weekChanges[2];
} SetpointChangesWeekSchedule_t;

static constexpr SetpointChangesWeekSchedule defaultSchedule = {{
   {{
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0}
   }},
   {{
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0},
   {0,  0}
   }}
}};
```

Explanation is: first braces are for object, second are for array inside object.

Compiler allows to use single set, like this:

```
struct Test
{
    int a[5];
};

Test t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

But in your case it will look like:

```
static constexpr SetpointChangesWeekSchedule defaultSchedule = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};
```

Which is probably too confusing.

Comment: I did exactly as you described but now I get a different error:




```error: too many braces around scalar initializer for type 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'}
   75 | }};
      |  ^```

Comment: Probably you added too many braces. Don't add them around inner-most int values. You can check my solution here: https://godbolt.org/z/xG9Moaz19

Comment: ```static constexpr SetpointChangesWeekSchedule defaultSchedule = {
    0,0,
    0,0,
    0,0,
    0,0,
    0,0,
    0,0,
    0,0,
    0,0
};```

Still gets me this error:

 ```error: too many initializers for 'const SetpointProgram::SetpointChangesWeekSchedule'
   87 | };```
      | ^

Comment: I forget to mention, that you seem to have error. You probably meant `SetpointChangesDaySchedule_t weekChanges[2];` instead of `SetpointChangeTime_t weekChanges[2];` as in your code.

Comment: Ah man you're totally right. That was it. So much time over a typo... Thank you!